Gradle cannot resolve dependency on Window, work well on MACOS
I tried to import a dependency to project, it work well on MACOS but on Window, the error occur:
Error
Failed to resolve: com.thelittlefireman:AppKillerManager:2.1.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details

When i tried to access the github page of this project, it cannot be found, same with the maven link
Here is my build gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        app_version_major = 8
        app_version_minor = 0
        app_version_patch = 7
        app_version_code = 8074
        app_version_code_dev = 0
        app_version_minor_dev = 0
        app_version_patch_dev = 1
        app_version_patch_plus = 0
        build_tools = '30.0.3'

        min_sdk = 24
        minSdkVersion = min_sdk
        target_sdk = 33
        compile_sdk = 33
        compileSdkVersion = 33

        mosby_mvp_version = '2.0.1'
        eventbus_version = '3.0.0'
        hotchemi_permission = '3.0.1'
        rx_android_version = '2.0.1'
        rx_java_version = '2.1.9'
        rx_adapter_retrofit_version = '1.0.0'
        dagger_version = '2.11'
        gson_version = '2.8.0'
        retrofit_version = '2.1.0'
        google_play_service_version = '17+'

        kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
        kotlinVersion = '1.9.10'
        picasso_version = '2.5.2'

        image_slider_version = 'v1.2.1'

        fire_base_core_version = '16.0.1'
        fire_base_messaging_version = '17.1.0'

        constraint_layout_version = '1.1.0'
        pubnub_version = '4.26.1'
        junit_version = '4.12'
        timber_version = '4.3.1'
        common_lang_version = '1.6'

        firebase_ui_auth_version = '4.1.0'
        firebase_auth = '17.0.0'

        android_state_version = '1.3.1'

        ripple_background_version = '1.0.3'

        /*used by shipper and pharmacy app, will be obsolete when introduce kotlin*/
//        butter_knife_version = '10.0.0'

        /*used by shipper, pharmacy app*/
        logging_interceptor_version = '3.3.1'

        coroutines_version  = '1.0.1'

        android_arch_paging_runtime_version = '1.0.1'

        android_arch_lifecycle_version = '1.1.1'

        /*used by user, pharmacy app*/
        compressor_image_version = '2.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
//        FilePicker
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'

//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'

        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
}

subprojects {...

        repositories{
            flatDir {
                dirs '../libs'
            }
        }
        dependencies {

             ...

            implementation 'com.thelittlefireman:AppKillerManager:2.1.1'

            ...
        }
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
}

...


Maybe something wrong with the gradle version ? Cus i tried on gradle 7.6 in my old project, it still work
